# Почему браузер выводит код страницы?

Tags: apache, symfony4

В symfony даже стартовую страницу выводит просто html-кодом. В chrome когда нажимаю на Просмотреть код, то видно, что все содержимое страницы почему-то в body и в pre. Что делать? Вся эта фигня на openserver. Но даже если встроенный сервер запускаю на symfony такая же фигня. Раньше такого не было. Хотя demo-приложение на symfony работает нормально. В логах пишет 'invalid request unexpected eof'

Comment: 'invalid request unexpected eof' похоже где-то стоит die() или exit() или echo()

Comment: Это происходит даже со стандартной страницей приветствия фрэймворка. Раньше такого не было. На второй винде также. Но на второй винде уже не пишет invalid request unexpected eof

Comment: `почему-то в body и в pre` может в главном шаблоне забыли незакрытый <pre> ?

Comment: Может быть дело в заголовках? В Firefox пишет Response Headers : Content-type : application/json.

Comment: Может и в этом. Надо смотреть настройки и код контроллеров

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в конфиге fos_rest. Вопрос закрыт. Спасибо.